# Dynamic Sprites as3

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, dynamic

I just cant figure out how to do this. Im not very familiar with as3 and it just keeps trowing errors at my face. One thing that bugs me most is not having a clue on what or when I need to import stuff.

Im using flash builder and Im simply trying to make it grab grab an image from a xml file and place it on screen with the possibility to click this image and expand a box with text under the image.

Can someone please outline what should I be looking at? I can get together the pieces of the puzzle but im usually just left with a pile of errors whose description I cant understand.

Comment: You're not providing any code or errors, so you're assuming people should just guess. As far as I can understand you are: 1. loading and xml and parsing it; 2. attempting to load an image using an url from xml; 3. adding a click event listener to scale a box(which ever that might be, maybe the image) with some text. Which part is failing first and what's the error message ?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply, I understand that without providing any code the best people can do is point me to references, but I don't think what I got is even worth posting is just some collage from kirupa and some other code which I think isnt going anywere.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of [tutorials](http://www.google.co.uk/search?&q=actionscript+3+tutorial+xml+gallery) out there in case you just want to get this done.

However if you understand more, it might be good to take this from the beginning. 
From the top of my mind [Practical Actionscript 3](http://wiki.mediaboxtraining.com/doku.php/flash:tutorials) is an excellent and free online resource to get started.

Comment: Thank you Theo, Ill give a look at that reference.

Answer (score 0):

A great place to start with Flash is [GotoAndLearn](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/).